# SQL Выборка SELECT группа с максимальным количеством элементов

Tags: sql, select

Есть таблица с именем Zoo вида:

```
|Kind | Name |                                                                  

|tiger| Joe  |                                                                 
|lion | Leo  |                                                                 
|puma| Max  |                                                                  
|tiger| Ken  |                                                                   
|lion | Alex |                                                                  
|tiger| Rob  |
```

Помогите составить запрос SQL
который бы выводил вид животного с максимальным количеством 
особей, то есть такого вида:

```
| tiger |
```

Comment: group by kind, сортировка по количеству и limit 1

Comment: Группировка по виду, сортировка по убыванию количества, взять первую запись.